# Open something with new url without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how can I open something in overlay with new url without reloading the page. As, reddit and facebook do. In new reddit design when we click on any post it is opened in overlay with new url.

Comment: can you show us how far you done

Comment: Asynchronous JavaScript And XML, in short: [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: You tagged your question with ajax. So you now what technology to use. What is you specific question?

Answer (score 2):

Two simple options, one using jquery and the other with vanilla JavaScript:

1. Create a div with initial `display: none` into which you can [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) whatever content you want from another page and set `display: block` when it should open.
2. Do the same as in 1. but use an iframe instead

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create an `iframe` and then write its document. I append the iframe, grab `innerHTML` of `foo` and write it to `iframe`.

#### Example of iFrame

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function createDynamicFrame() {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        var html   = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
        iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
        iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="foo">
        I come home in the morning light <br/>
        My mother says when you gonna live your life right <br/>
        Oh mother dear we're not the fortunate ones <br/>
        And girls they wanna have fun <br/>
        Oh girls just want to have function <br/> <br/>
      </div>
       <button onclick="createDynamicFrame()">Click me</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Tested on [Code Ground Online JavaScript Compiler](http://%20http://tpcg.io/i4i0t1).

Second method would be to use `window.open()` and write to the document.

#### Example of Window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function createWindow() {
        var win    = window.open()
        var html   = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
        win.document.open();
        win.document.write(html);
        win.document.close();
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="foo">
        I come home in the morning light <br/>
        My mother says when you gonna live your life right <br/>
        Oh mother dear we're not the fortunate ones <br/>
        And girls they wanna have fun <br/>
        Oh girls just want to have function <br/>
      </div>
       <button onclick="createWindow()">Click me</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Tested on [Code Ground Online JavaScript Compiler](http://%20http://tpcg.io/aakitr).

I'm sure many more possibilities exists such as with jQuery.

> [JavaScript and iFrames](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/)